# How to keep apache and mysql from starting automatically

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, apache2, mysql

Is there a way to make apache and mysql not run automatically on startup?

Currently, whenever I boot my machine, they start automatically and run in the background.

I am using Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

### Apache

```
sudo update-rc.d -f apache2 disable
```

Apache is still using rc.d init script, which is why you must disable it using `update-rc.d`.

### MySQL

```
echo manual | sudo tee /etc/init/mysql.override
```

MySQL on the other hand has converted to an upstart configuration file. The recommended way of disabling upstart services is to use an override file.

Comment: Do i have to do this on every startup

Comment: Nope, only once.. The changes are persistent. :)

Comment: A cleanest way to disable autostart for any service with a `.conf` file in `/etc/init` (like mysql), is to run as root: `echo "manual" >> /etc/init/[service_name].override`.

Comment: kudo @el.atomo [Manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man5/init.5.html) **Event Definition** *"manual" This stanza will disregard any previously seen **start on** definition. By adding this stanza on any line below the **start on** definition, it provides the ability to stop a job from  being automatically started. When specified, the only way to start such a job is via **start***. -- Also, take a look at **Override File Handling** *Override files allow a jobs environment to be changed without modifying the jobs configuration file.*

Comment: Also this will work too: `sudo mv /etc/init/cups.conf /etc/cups.conf.disabled`. It's easier to see what services are disabled when you do this. Re: [Can you remove printer support (cups)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/97666/can-you-remove-printer-scaner-support)

Comment: Can you use `update-rc.d` on MySQL?

Comment: @Shurane Sadly, no.

Comment: it seems to me that mysql only starts with apache by default, so I only need to disable apache.

Answer (score 10):

For all system services in `/etc/init.d`, disabling them can be done with the [`update-rc.d`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/update-rc.d.8.html) command, e.g.:

```
update-rc.d -f apache2 remove
```

To restore it to running on startup:

```
update-rc.d apache2 defaults
```

You can also manually start and stop via `service apache2 start` and `service apache2 stop`.

Answer (score 5):

Run the following in a terminal:

```
update-rc.d -f apache2 remove

update-rc.d -f mysql remove
```

see:
http://www.aboutlinux.info/2006/04/enabling-and-disabling-services-during_01.html

Comment: Do i have to do this on every startup

Comment: Sorry for my late reply (just saw your message). You don't have to do that every time it boots, it should stick