# System hangs during boot at "Starting MySQL server [OK]"

Tags: boot

I have Ubuntu 12.04 installed on my machine (Dual boot). It was working fine till today.
I executed the following commands in the terminal, and when I restarted I get a Purple Screen of Death.

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

I also had Qt Designer installed, so I removed it using

```
sudo apt-get remove qt4-dev-tools
sudo apt-get remove qt4-docs
sudo apt-get remove qt4-assistant
sudo apt-get remove qt4-linguist
```

I had already tried the following:

1. In recovery mode, it always hangs at this part.

   ```
   * Starting MySQL server [OK]
   ```
2. From a Ubuntu Forum post, I tried doing Ctrl+Alt+F1 and then

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get upgrade
   sudo apt-get install fglrx
   sudo aticonfig --initial
   ```

But this always ends with aticonfig:No supported adapters detected.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

P.S : Please do not mark this as duplicate as I've gone through many threads and I'm not able to find a solution myself.

EDIT: it now hangs at Checking battery state itself :( . 
I've referred to this http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1606130 but I'm unable to find any solution.

Comment: Suggest you visit http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it

Comment: Edit your boot parameters in grub (press `e` then look for the line ending in `quiet splash`) remove `quiet splash` and write `verbose`. Then try booting your system again.

Answer (score 0):

If it is hanging at `* Starting MySQL server [OK]` you should try disabling MySQL server (via Ctrl+Alt+F1) and then see if it continues past that stage when you reboot.

You can do this as follows:

```
sudo nano /etc/init/mysql.conf
```

Comment out (using a hash sign) the `start on` section - and this section **only**! If it spans multiple lines, add a hash sign to each line.

For example:

```
#start on (net-device-up
          #and local-filesystems
          #and runlevel [2345])
```

Instructions from: [How to keep apache and mysql from starting automatically](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138487/how-to-keep-apache-and-mysql-from-starting-automatically)

Comment: Ummm.. How do I do that?

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but now it hangs before. I've edited my question. :(

Comment: Hmmm, I'm out of ideas then, sorry. Hopefully someone else comes along with more knowledge than me.

Answer (score -2):

To restore your ubuntu 12.04 do a version upgrade to Ubuntu 12.10 via USB and you will have the problem fixed.

You could also do a clean install of the latest 13.10 to avoid any future problems as it is the most updated stable version for Ubuntu and as you are not an Enterprise you don´t need LTS versions.

PS: if you boot into the system run the following on the terminal:

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get -f upgrade`

`sudo apt-get -f dist-upgrade`    (this last one doesn´t update your system to a new Ubuntu verison)

Hope it helped you out.

Comment: They don't have to upgrade to 12.10 just to fix this.  This answer is incorrect, however it is still an attempt at an answer.